# building ES6 parser and string generator

Tags: javascript, oop, parsing, recursion, ecmascript-6

I am building a parser for a personal project I wish to make open source once I meet my initial goals. I am having some trouble with the recursive call which I am doing to build the DOM dynamically. I do not wish to use any framework at all to do this.

Basically, my code generator builds a DOM string out of a Javascript array to represent the DOM, and objects to simulate the elements themselves.

```
  var example = [{elm: 'div',
  class: 'fadeIn',
  inner: 'Hello!'}]
```

Would produce

```
  <div class="fadeIn">Hello!</div>
```

And

```
  var module = [{elm: 'div',   
  class: 'background-yellow',
  inner: example 
  }]
```

Would produce

```
<div class="background-yellow">
  <div class="fadeIn">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

My code below produces the first example relatively well, although I have documented several things to make it complete (such as self closing tags). The part that I am struggling with is the nested objects which represent nested nodes. I aim to do this recursively but feel free to use an iterative approach - if you can help, who am I to judge :)

```
// Start with a single node
var testDom = [{
    elm: 'button',
    inner: 'click me!',
    class: 'test-elm',
    onclick: 'javascript:alert("woot!");',
}]

var nestedTest = [{
    elm: 'div',
    inner: testDom
}]

// Define
class parser {

    // This is the parser for JSML
    constructor(stdIn) {
        this.output = '';
        this.parse(stdIn);
        return this.output;
    }

    generateAttributeKeyValueString(key, value) {
        return `${key}='${value}'`;
    }

    generateDom(vNode, nestedOpenTag, nestedCloseTag) {
        var self = this,
            elmStart = `<${vNode.elm}`,
            elmEnd = `</${vNode.elm}>`,
            elmAttrs = '',
            elmContent;
        function parseInput(vNode, key) {
            // if (!vNode.hasOwnProperty(key)) return;
            var value = vNode[key];
            // custom types conditons depending on the key and value of the nodes contents
            var isActualInnerValueChildContents = (key === 'inner' && typeof value !== 'object');
            var isChildrenContentArr = (key === 'inner' && Array.isArray(value));
            var isAttributeKeyValuePair = (key !== 'elm' && key !== 'inner');

            if (isActualInnerValueChildContents) elmContent = value;
            else if (isAttributeKeyValuePair) elmAttrs += self.generateAttributeKeyValueString(key, value); // Otherwise its an attribute and value pair and should be added to the node string
            else if (isChildrenContentArr) {
                // Array of nested child nodes.
                elmStart += ` ${elmAttrs}>`;
                self.generateDom(value, elmStart, elmEnd)
            }
        }   

        for (var key in vNode) parseInput(vNode, key);

        elmStart += ` ${elmAttrs}>`; // Close off the html elements start tag now that all possible attributes have been written



        if (nestedOpenTag && nestedCloseTag) this.output = nestedOpenTag + this.output + nestedCloseTag;
        else this.output = elmStart + elmContent + elmEnd;
    }

    parse(input) {
        var self = this;
        input.forEach((vNode) => {
            self.generateDom(vNode);
        });
    }

}

parser.execute = function(vDom) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML += vDom.output;
    return vDom;
}

// Call
console.log(parser.execute(new parser(testDom)).output);
```

*Here is a [link](http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/WxyoRA/?editors=1010) to show the code working on the single node.*

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: So close... but so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things I found:

#### Fixing the main problem

When you get an `inner` value that's just plain text, you set the element's content (`elmContent`) to that text

When you get an `inner` value that's another element, what I understand is that you want to get the parsed version of that element, and set the element's content to that resulting text.

To get the parsed version of another element, you could just parse it regularly and do do `parser.execute(new parser(<element>)).output`

So in `generateDom`, just set `elmContent` to `parser.execute(new parser(value)).output` when `value` is another element, just like you set it to `value` when `value` was regular text. Instead of doing this:

```
if (isChildrenContentArr) {
    // Array of nested child nodes.
    elmStart += ` ${elmAttrs}>`;
    self.generateDom(value, elmStart, elmEnd)
}
```

Do this:

```
if (isChildrenContentArr) {
    // Array of nested child nodes.
    elmContent = parser.execute(new parser(value)).output
}
```

You don't even need to think about the recursion. Just remember that you're setting the element content to the `value`, parsed

The last two arguments to `generateDOM` are never used, so remove them like so:

```
generateDom(vNode) { ...
```

#### Parsing content that is multiple DOM Elements

Applying the above fix will make some of your elements work, where the `inner` content is just one sub-element, like in

```
var nestedTest = [{
    elm: 'div',
    inner: testDom
}]
```

But in others, it's an array, like in

```
var app = [{
    elm: 'body',
    inner: [
        header,
        content,
        footer
    ]
}]
```

Another thing I noticed is that all of these elements are in arrays. I think you're assuming the arrays flatten, so that something like

```
[ [element1], [element2], [element3] ]
```

turns into

```
[element1, element2, element3]
```

However, this doesn't happen in javascript, and you just end up having an array containing other arrays. So when you apply the above code and `value` is an array of elements, not just one element, it won't work.

First of all, you probably should remove all of the arrays surrounding the elements, so an element like

```
var app = [{
    elm: 'body',
    inner: [
        header,
        content,
        footer
    ]
}]
```

turns into

```
var app = {
    elm: 'body',
    inner: [
        header,
        content,
        footer
    ]
}
```

(Notice the lack of `[...]` around the definition)

To allow your parser to parse these, just change the `parse` function in your `parser` to:

```
parse(input) {
    var self = this;
    self.generateDom(input);
}
```

Then, handle the cases where `value` is one element and when it's multiple elements separately; when assigning `value` in `parseInput`, add `isSingleChildContent` do:

```
var value = vNode[key],
// custom types conditons depending on the key and value of the nodes contents
isActualInnerValueChildContents = (key === 'inner' && typeof value === 'string'),
isChildrenContentArr = (key === 'inner' && Array.isArray(value)),
isSingleChildContent = (key === 'inner' && !isChildrenContentArr && (typeof value === 'object')),
isAttributeKeyValuePair = (key !== 'elm' && key !== 'inner');
```

Notice how `isActualInnerValueChildContents` is true if `value` is a string, and not just any non-object value. `isChildrenContentArr` is true if `value` is an array, like before. And `isSingleChildContent`, the new test, is true if `value` is an object and not an array, which would be a single element (having removed the `[...]`s surrounding all the element variables).

Now, if the `inner` `value` is a single element, the `elmContent` will be that element parsed (`parser.execute(new parser(value)).output`). But if it's multiple values, you have to enumerate each value and add it's result to `elmContent`, like this:

```
//Array of multiple child nodes
elmContent = "";

value.forEach((subValue) => {
    elmContent += parser.execute(new parser(subValue)).output;
});
```

---

Here is the final code, in a snippet. This should work for all of your elements (I've only tested a couple though):

```js
/** JSML - Javascript markup language

 Benifits over traditional HTML:
  1) Remove 1 of 3 languages you must know in order to work on the front end of websites (HTML), drastically reducing the complexity of web development
  2) HTML is not flexible, JSML is as flexible as can be
  3) Much tinier syntax compared to HTML, each DOM node is represented by a simple JSON object the DOM is an array no closing tags needed either
  4) Dynamically manipulate elements with no extra frameworks needed - just use plain JS
  5) Framework and platform independant, works with 100% client side and server side libraries out there (it doesnt change anything other than your development process).
  6) Completely manage DOM elements by name instead of selector (very powerful)
  
  Major milestones remaining for v1
  1) Recursive algorithm (right now only generates a single layer of non-nested nodes)
  2) Handling for - seperated data-attributes (camelCase to hyphen-case)
  3) Consistancy between sever and client event assignment
  4) Handling for self closing tags
**/

// Input (language syntax example for static and dynamic)

// Static vNode with dynamic contents
var navigation = {
 elm: 'navigation',
 inner: menuItems(),
 class: 'navigation'
}

// Example of managing the element without explicitly describing the selector more than one time

function sampleMethodBinding(){
 alert();
}

// Dynamically created vNodes
function menuItems() {
 var items = []
 var data = [{
  elm: 'a',
  inner: 'Click here!'
 }, {
  elm: 'a',
  inner: 'here too!'
 }]

 data.forEach(function(itemData, idx) {items.push({
  elm: itemData.elm,
  href: '/page' + idx + '.html',
  inner: 'Nav item #' + idx,
 })});

 return items;
}

var header = {
 elm: 'header',
 inner: navigation,
 class: 'header'
}

var content = {
 elm: 'body',
 inner: 'This is the content area!!!',
 class: 'content'
}

var footer = {
 elm: 'footer',
 inner: navigation,
 class: 'footer'
}

// This is the virtual DOM parent
var app = {
 elm: 'body',
 inner: [
  header,
  content,
  footer
 ]
}

// Start with a single node
var testDom = {
 elm: 'button',
 inner: 'click me!',
 class: 'test-elm',
 onclick: 'javascript:alert("woot!");',
}

var nestedTest = {
 elm: 'div',
 inner: testDom
}

// Define
class parser {

 // This is the parser for JSML
 constructor(stdIn) {
  this.output = '';
  this.parse(stdIn);
  return this.output;
 }

 generateAttributeKeyValueString(key, value) {
  return `${key}='${value}'`;
 }

 generateDom(vNode) {
  var self = this,
   elmStart = `<${vNode.elm}`,
   elmEnd = `</${vNode.elm}>`,
   elmAttrs = '',
   elmContent;
  function parseInput(vNode, key) {
    if (!vNode.hasOwnProperty(key)) return;
    var value = vNode[key],
    // custom types conditons depending on the key and value of the nodes contents
    isActualInnerValueChildContents = (key === 'inner' && typeof value === 'string'),
    isChildrenContentArr = (key === 'inner' && Array.isArray(value)),
    isSingleChildContent = (key === 'inner' && !isChildrenContentArr && (typeof value === 'object')),
       isAttributeKeyValuePair = (key !== 'elm' && key !== 'inner');

   if (isActualInnerValueChildContents) elmContent = value;
   else if (isAttributeKeyValuePair) elmAttrs += self.generateAttributeKeyValueString(key, value); // Otherwise its an attribute and value pair and should be added to the node string
   else if (isChildrenContentArr) {
    //Array of multiple child nodes
    elmContent = "";
    
    value.forEach(function(subValue) {
     elmContent += parser.execute(new parser(subValue)).output;
    });
   } else if (isSingleChildContent) {
    // Just one child node
    elmContent = parser.execute(new parser(value)).output;
   }
   
  } 

  for (var key in vNode) parseInput(vNode, key);

  elmStart += ` ${elmAttrs}>`; // Close off the html elements start tag now that all possible attributes have been written
  
  this.output = elmStart + elmContent + elmEnd;
 }

 parse(input) {
  var self = this;
  self.generateDom(input);
 }

}

parser.execute = function(vDom) {
 document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML += vDom.output;
 return vDom;
}

// Call
document.innerHtml = parser.execute(new parser(app)).output;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So I am not understanding how the flattened array issue is caused by the app object not being wrapped in an array... but I did encounter an issue when debugging similar to what you describe.  But.. thank you so much!! :) you fixed with with less change than I was expecting